# Boot Image from Running System (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, iso-image

I have a Linux system running in another place, which I use as processing server, now I'm adquiring a new one and I would like to export all the configuration programs and maybe folder structure to the new one. However I cant not access phisically. I would like to know if there is a way of downloading or creating a boot image to install on my new device directly from the running device, via SCP or something like that.

If that isn't posible, what are your suggestions to export the configuration to the new computer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not try to make an image of a mounted filesystem. Nor is copying an open file a good idea (you could end up with a snapshot of mismatched data). You could install the same Linux distro (that's on the old system) on the new system, along with the necessary packages and applications. Then (assuming you know what they are) copy over (using NFS or TFTP) just the relevant configuration files. If you want to copy the data files, you will need to shutdown the application(s) (or use the backups).